# Favicon is loading very late

Tags: performance

I have 2-3 WordPress sites all have same problem when it comes to website speed. Everything is loading within 2 seconds except Favcion, how can i load the favicon faster?

Comment: Is the favicon actually loading slowly, i.e. if you look in your browser debug tools or server logs you see a 2 second request for the favicon, or is it just your browser isn't requesting it right away?

Comment: How do i know if the browser is not requesting right away?

Comment: Open your browser's debug tools on the 'network' or similar tab and reload the page, and look at the sequence of requests. Is favicon at the bottom, and does the timing bar show it starting late? Or does it start at the same time as everything else but just take longer to complete?

Comment: It's requesting in the end.